# Transferring data from old 18.04machine to new 20.04 one

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, transfer

I just built a new system running 20.04 and need to move the data from an old system that is running 18.04... What is the best way to transfer all of the files (minus the o/s)?

Comment: Personally I prefer to create and install onto an existing /home directory so the old files are discovered & used (ie. it maybe a new disk, but I've placed my data there and I install without format).  In your case I'd just copy the data there (`cp -prn` nothing any directories missed which I'd evaluate (are they significant? will I miss that data? if a configuration file, can I easily re-create what I like which would be my preference to copying the older config onto a new system). Please note I'm talking data files (not system, system files are fine before install as they'll be erased..)

Comment: ps:  I'd likely do that via 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media) to ensure files are not in use. I would not do it whilst logged into a GUI session (you didn't say if you're talking about server or desktop...)  The mentioned `cp` was used as example, as it maybe `scp`, `rsync` etc over network, but the method I'd choose would depend on the older system, how it was used, what software is installed etc.. details we don't have).

Comment: (minus the o/s)... What do you mean by that?

Comment: exactly what data do you need to move,your home folder? ,your installed programs?if you only want to keep documents-pictures-videos and things like that you just copy your home folder to an external drive.